# RestSharp - Serialization and "[XmlAttribute]"

Tags: restsharp

RestSharp - I have a class which contains nested classes.

```
public class Extension
{
    public ID ID { get; set; }
    public Extension()
    {
        ID = new ID();
    }
}

public class ID
{
    public string typeCode { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to serialise an instance using RestSharp

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer("HellThere");
string myXml = xmlSerializer.Serialize(getCatalog);
```

This work perfectly, and gives me (snippet)

```xml
<Extension>
  <ID>
    <typeCode>PriceListShortName</typeCode>
    <Value>GLUS</Value>
  </ID>
</Extension>
```

But what I want is

```xml
<Extension>
  <ID typeCode="PriceListShortName">GLUS</ID>
</Extension>
```

I've based my class ID on the "public class Image" suggestion at
[RestSharp Documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Serialization)

I've also tried using

```
public class ID
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("typeCode")]
    public string typeCode { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

But that doesn't fix it. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

I changed

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer("HelloThere");

to

DotNetXmlSerializer xmlSerialiser = new DotNetXmlSerializer("HelloThere");

And now it works!!